# How to make bootstrap website lose all responsive features within 786px width?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, viewport

Here's my problem. I've got a website based on Bootstrap and I just want it to act as an unresponsive site when visited from devices with width less than 768px. And when the width is more than 768px, it should be responsive as usual.

Below is what I've tried.
My global viewport setting:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">
```

I also tried to add css snippet like

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  @viewport {
    width: 1024px !important;
  }
}
```

because I want to make it look like the width is 1024px. But this doesn't work as I expected.

So anyone who has dealt with similar issues please give me some advice. Thanks.

Comment: To solve the problem, rather than answer the question, perhaps you could use a server-side system such as [Mobile-Detect](https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect) to detect when the end-users screen is too small, and send back a static image in that case.

Comment: When you say "doesn't work as expected," what do you mean?

Comment: Just out of curiosity: why would you do this? Also, Bootstrap is designed for mobile first...

Answer (score 1):

From [Bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#disable-responsive):

> **Steps to disable page responsiveness**
>
> 1. Omit the viewport `<meta>` mentioned in [the CSS docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-mobile)
> 2. Override the `width` on the `.container` for each grid tier with a single width, for example `width: 970px !important;` Be sure that this comes after the default Bootstrap CSS. You can optionally avoid the `!important` with media queries or some selector-fu.
> 3. If using navbars, remove all navbar collapsing and expanding behavior.
>      For grid layouts, use `.col-xs-*` classes in addition to, or in place of, the medium/large ones. Don't worry, the extra-small device grid scales to all resolutions.

---

**Conditionally omitting the viewport**

The best way to manipulate `viewport` dynamically is to use JavaScript. Give your viewport `meta` element a `id` so you can change it when the width of window is changed. For example:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" id="viewport">

<script>
    window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
        var vp = document.getElementById("viewport");
        if (window.innerWidth <= 768) {
            vp.setAttribute('content', '');
        } else {
            vp.setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1');
        }
    }, true);
</script>
```

**Override styles**

Just use the media query, as you already did.

Answer (score 0):

The following example should get you what you want. Note that I defined `@viewport` directly in the css.

**CSS**

```
.col-md-2 {
  height:200px;
}
@viewport {
  width:device-width;
  initial-scale:1;
}

@media (min-width: 1000px) {
.col-md-2 {
    background:#ff0000;
    width:100%;
    zoom:.1;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 1000px){
.col-md-2 {
    background:#fff000;
    width:200px;
  }
  @viewport {
    width:1000px;
    initial-scale:1;
    zoom: 1;
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
</div>
```

And here's a [link](http://www.bootply.com/gmB9RA6LDU) to a working version of the example. As you can see, the zoom factor changes dramatically when the browser is resized.

Lastly, you should note that `@viewport` is not a formal standard as of the moment. [This](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units) page has a list of supported browsers.